# Autofac - Mvc 5 beta - DependencyResolver fails to get type

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, autofac, asp.net-mvc-5

I just converted an MVC 4 project to MVC 5 beta (and a Web Api project to Web Api 2) and I'm having some issues with `DependencyResolver` not being able to resolve the class I need.

Here is the class I want to resolve:

```
 public class GetPartsQueryValidationHandler
    : IQueryValidationHandler<GetPartsQuery, Part[]>
{
    ...
}
```

Here is how I register it with Autofac in Bootstrapper.cs ( I do this in both projects):

```
 builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(dataAccessAssembly)
               .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IQueryValidationHandler<,>))
               .InstancePerHttpRequest(); //..PerApiRequest in Web Api
```

I also register the DependencyResolver in both projects :

In Mvc Project:

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

In Web Api Project:

```
 GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
```

Then in a third project I call the following to resolve the reference:

```
 var handlerType = typeof(IQueryValidationHandler<,>).MakeGenericType(query.GetType(), typeof(TResult));
 dynamic handler = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(handlerType);
```

But this gives me a null `handler`

I need to resolve that class somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I figured out how to replace DependencyResolver... this seems to be an anti pattern when constructor dependency is an option. I couldn't figure out how to make it work before but I gave it another go and looks like all you need is an `IComponentContext` constructor parameter and Autofac will take care of it by default:

```
public class DefaultQueryBus : IQueryBus
{
    private readonly IComponentContext componentContext;

    public DefaultQueryBus(IComponentContext componentContext)
    {
        this.componentContext = componentContext;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate<TResult>(IQuery<TResult> query)
    {
        var handlerType = typeof(IQueryValidationHandler<,>).MakeGenericType(query.GetType(), typeof(TResult));
        dynamic handler = this.componentContext.Resolve(handlerType); //Good
    }
}
```